# Pinned section in sidebar menu?

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have a feature that i want to add to my sidebar menu.

My menu consists in something like this:

```
---------------------
Folder 1
\------> action 1
\------> action 2
\------> action X
---------------------
---------------------
Folder 2
\------> action 1
\------> action X
---------------------
---------------------
Folder 3
\------> action 1
---------------------
---------------------
Folder 4
---------------------
```

And the users of my website works with they different folders but i want a button in each folder that allow the user to "pin" the folder that the user will use more often in the day. Something like a button that once pressed it moves that folder section to the top.

The HTML of each folder is something like this:

```
<li>
   <div class="droppable folder expanded">
       <div class="folder_content">
           <div class="folder_name">
               Folder 1
           </div>
           <div class="folder_extra">
               <ul class="modules">
                   <li>action 1</li>
                   ......
                   <li>action X</li>
               </ul>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution. It used prepend to set the folder into the pinned section. Next would be to use local storage to hold the order of the pinned items.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neoaptt/dLaq9rv9/)

```js
$('.pin').click(function () {
    var file = $(this).closest('.folder_content');
    file.prependTo('.pinned');
});
```

```css
.pinned, .unpinned {
    border:black solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='pinned'></div>
<div class='unpinned'>
    <div class="folder_content">
        <div class="folder_name">Folder 1</div>
        <button class='pin'>Pin</button>
        <div class="folder_extra">
            <ul class="modules">
                <li>action 1</li>......
                <li>action X</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="folder_content">
        <div class="folder_name">Folder 2</div>
        <button class='pin'>Pin</button>
        <div class="folder_extra">
            <ul class="modules">
                <li>action 1</li>......
                <li>action X</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="folder_content">
        <div class="folder_name">Folder 3</div>
        <button class='pin'>Pin</button>
        <div class="folder_extra">
            <ul class="modules">
                <li>action 1</li>......
                <li>action X</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="folder_content">
        <div class="folder_name">Folder 4</div>
        <button class='pin'>Pin</button>
        <div class="folder_extra">
            <ul class="modules">
                <li>action 1</li>......
                <li>action X</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```